# Asp.NET MVC 3 ModelBinding Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to disable the automatic validation of 
a Model gets passed to a Controller... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ModelValidatorProviderCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidatorprovidercollection.aspx) allows you to control what kinds of validation providers your application will use.  By default I believe it uses the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`.

You could try clearing out the collection at application startup -- I've never tried it, but I would imagine that would disable validation for you.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Other startup code...

    ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bound model only validates (client side) out of the [MVC3] box. When you scaffold a view, *jquery.validate.min.js* and *jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js* are added to the view if you leave the "Reference script libraries" check box ticked. This will produce some *client* side validation.

If you remove the references to these scripts, the validation is not done server side (in your controller) unless you access:

```
ModelState.IsValid
```

You could have `[Required]` attributes, your own custom `ValidationAttribute` annotations, etc and the model will not be validated.

Comment: I have tried it, but cant confirm. My ValidationAttributes get
validated without calling ModelState.IsValid.

Comment: @dknaack: What can't you confirm? Can you show some model code?